# JAXB Unmarshalling Using @XMLJavaTypeAdapters

Tags: java, jaxb

I Am having three classes

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GeofenceParameter{

    private GeofenceCenterAddress geofenceCenterAddress;

    private GeofenceCenterCoordinates geofenceCenterCoordinates;
}

public class  GeofenceCenterAddress extends GeofenceParameter{

}

public class  GeofenceCenterCoordinate extends GeofenceParameter{

}
```

I Have made two different XmlAdapter extended classes to marshall and unmarshall the Geofence Paramtere in GeofenceCenterAddress And GeofenceCentereCoordinate

```
Class forGeofenceCenterCoordinate extends XmlAdapter<ValueType,BoundType>{
}

Class forGeofenceCenterAddress extends XmlAdapter<ValueType,BoundType>{
}
```

for getting the instance of releated to either GeofenceCenterAddress or GeofenceCenterCoordinate class from GeofenceParamter depending upon Soap request send.

For This i have used annotation in package-info.java file `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters{(@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=forGeofenceCenterCoordinate)),@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=forGeofenceCenterAddress)}`

But In Web Service it will give me the instance of class which i have specified fist in the annotation i.e of this `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=forGeofenceCenterCoordinate) class not of @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=forGeofenceCenterAddress)` from GeofenceParamter.

Can U Please Help me in geeting the instance of second class also in JAXB inheritence Marshalling And Unmarshalling.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember having used `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters`, but the normal usage of the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation would simply be `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(forGeofenceCenterCoordinate.class)`.

The type parameter is only necessary if the annotation is applied at the package level.